# Strange series of page visits to my web site

Tags: security, spam, logs

In my web log I see 5 hits (to the same web page) all about the same time but from different parts of the world:

```
180.247.114.192         /RelFinder?personId=17586 - From: null  2014-01-10 00:26:40.0   Opera/9.64(Windows NT 5.1; U; en) Presto/2.1.1
202.118.236.130         /RelFinder?personId=7985 - From: null   2014-01-10 00:26:31.0   Opera/9.64(Windows NT 5.1; U; en) Presto/2.1.1
200.161.80.111      /RelFinder?personId=17679 - From: null  2014-01-10 00:26:31.0   Opera/9.64(Windows NT 5.1; U; en) Presto/2.1.1
186.222.83.170      /RelFinder?personId=17454 - From: null  2014-01-10 00:26:31.0   Opera/9.64(Windows NT 5.1; U; en) Presto/2.1.1
119.110.81.210      /RelFinder?personId=16801 - From: null  2014-01-10 00:26:30.0   Opera/9.64(Windows NT 5.1; U; en) Presto/2.1.1
```

Any idea why someone would do this? I've seen a couple other visits like this in the past but usually just 2 visits from two different sites at the same time.

Comment: Proxies? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server

Answer (score 4):

These hits are from a content spammer using multiple proxy IP addresses to hide their own IP address.

These attempts are often logged in [honeypot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honeypot_%28computing%29) projects by IP address and can be searched on there like I've done [here](https://www.projecthoneypot.org/ip_180.247.114.192).

You can also lookup IP addresses in proxy databases like I've done [here](http://old.cool-proxy.net/index.php?action=ip-info&ip=186.222.83.170).

A search for the path of the URL shows that it's part of a web application (without a [captcha](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA)) used to search for people (do a search engine search on:  `RelFinder?personId=`).

You can safely ignore these hits, however if they're bothersome to you then look into blocking them with a security module like [ModSecurity](http://www.modsecurity.org/), or create firewall rules to filter them out.